# Build URL Using GA Attributes

Tags: url, google-tag-manager, url-parameters

Good Day All

I am completely new to this type of query but is it possible to define a url on a button click on a page that populates the/a URL with information form the Google Tag stack? e.g. Campaign, Source etc?

Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two method that you can use to create a GA Attributes tagged url
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

&

http://www.utm.io/

Comment: Thanks for this. Close to what I want to do, but not quite. I'd like to build the url on a button click but lets say I want to capture the Medium of the visitor and use that in the URL, the URL is going to be used to pass these parameters to another system. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Universal analytics doesn't allow to check visitors medium or source. You could add additional classic (old) google analytics which stores source, medium etc. in cookies(__umtz). Then just parse cookie, check medium and do whatever you want with it. As I sad in new (universal analytics) there's no way to easy check medium.

Comment: Ahh OK, I'll see if we still have the old world tagged, have a feeling we dont. Thanks for your help.